# Kubectl can't connect on Windows 10

Tags: docker, gcloud, kubectl

I have recently installed `Docker` and the `gcloud SDK` on a Windows 10 machine.

After running `gcloud init` and configuring my local setup, I ran `gcloud components install kubectl`.

Now when I run `kubectl get pods` I get the response

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.

I then ran `kubectl config view` and got the following

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

I'm not sure how to fix this on Windows as I am normally a Mac user so this is all new to me.

How can my instance of `kubectl` connect?

Comment: You don't have kubectl defined to use any cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you want to configure your kubectl to use your GKE cluster, you have to run below commands to copy k8s configuration to local.

1.First list your cluster names (under NAME column) and recognize zone (under Location column)

```
$ gcloud container clusters list
```

2.Then run below command to copy k8s config to local

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name> --zone <zone>
```

3.Then check config

```
$ kubectl config view
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw people running into this issue on Windows by not realizing that in File Explorer file extensions are hidden by default, so while they wanted to create a file called "config", they actually created a file called "config.txt" and that's not found by kubectl.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting windows and install Ubuntu. Windows was a nightmare.